# How to download from ftp server using maven

Tags: maven, ant, ftp

We have tried using ant ftp tasks, but could not get it working like shown below:

```
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ftp</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <ftp action="get" server="192.168.168.xxx" userid="anonymous"
                                password="anonymous">
                                <fileset dir="Folder/tools/toolX">
                                    <include name="**/*.*" />
                                </fileset>
                            </ftp>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                ....
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why does it not work? any exceptions/ error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maven-antrun-plugin provides ant runtime with base set of tasks only.
For other tasks you need to provide them as dependencies (with their dependencies, if needed).
'ftp' case is used as an example of this problem on maven's site, you may find complete example there:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/customTasks.html

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly!

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <ftp action="get"
                         server="192.168.1.1"
                         remotedir="remoteDir"
                         userid="anonymous"
                         password="anonymous">
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}">
                            <include name="**/*.*"/>
                        </fileset>
                    </ftp>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-commons-net</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```